# XSLT Sequential Numbers in XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML

```
<root>
    <qryXMLOrders>
        <IteNumGDS7></IteNumGDS7>
        <GroMasGDS46>AA</GroMasGDS46>
        <NetMasGDS48>AA</NetMasGDS48>
    </qryXMLOrders>
    <qryXMLOrders>
        <IteNumGDS7></IteNumGDS7>
        <GroMasGDS46>BB</GroMasGDS46>
        <NetMasGDS48>BB</NetMasGDS48>
    </qryXMLOrders>
    <qryXMLOrders>
        <IteNumGDS7></IteNumGDS7>
        <GroMasGDS46>CC</GroMasGDS46>
        <NetMasGDS48>CC</NetMasGDS48>
    </qryXMLOrders>
</root>
```

and I'd like to have sequential numbers in the element  so the desired result will be like:

```
<root>
    <qryXMLOrders>
        <IteNumGDS7>1</IteNumGDS7>
        <GroMasGDS46>AA</GroMasGDS46>
        <NetMasGDS48>AA</NetMasGDS48>
    </qryXMLOrders>
    <qryXMLOrders>
        <IteNumGDS7>2</IteNumGDS7>
        <GroMasGDS46>BB</GroMasGDS46>
        <NetMasGDS48>BB</NetMasGDS48>
    </qryXMLOrders>
    <qryXMLOrders>
        <IteNumGDS7>3</IteNumGDS7>
        <GroMasGDS46>CC</GroMasGDS46>
        <NetMasGDS48>CC</NetMasGDS48>
    </qryXMLOrders>
</root>
```

How can this be done using XSLT?

Comment: Please check your sample input - it's not valid Xml with all those opening `<qryXMLOrders>` never being closed.

Comment: Yes sorry the sample input is: `<root>
<qryXMLOrders>
<IteNumGDS7></IteNumGDS7>
<GroMasGDS46>AA</GroMasGDS46>
<NetMasGDS48>AA</NetMasGDS48>
</qryXMLOrders>
<qryXMLOrders>
<IteNumGDS7></IteNumGDS7>
<GroMasGDS46>BB</GroMasGDS46>
<NetMasGDS48>BB</NetMasGDS48>
</qryXMLOrders>
<qryXMLOrders>
<IteNumGDS7></IteNumGDS7>
<GroMasGDS46>CC</GroMasGDS46>
<NetMasGDS48>CC</NetMasGDS48>
</qryXMLOrders>
</root>`

Comment: It's pretty easy to do this with the help of the `<xsl:number>` element.  If you need further assistance then consider showing what you've tried so that we know how best to help.

Comment: See also the `position()` function: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-position

Comment: Thanks! It was easy using the <xsl:number> :)