# sequence number value for element in different node

Tags: xslt

Based on counting element names which are located in different node. I want to give unique but sequence numbers.
 input Data

```
<record>
    `enter code here` <items>
        <list code="a">  item location </list>
        <list code="b"> 123 </list>
     </items>
    <items>
        <list code="a">  item location </list>
        <list code="b"> 123 </list>
     </items>
</record>
```

Desired output

```
<record>
     <items>
        <list code="a">  item location </list>
        <list code="b">1 </list>
     </items>
    <items>
        <list code="a">  item location </list>
        <list code="b"> 2 </list>
     </items>
</record>
```

Comment: Is the "\`enter code here\` " in your input to be taken as erroneous?

Comment: Yours is very similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43333219/xslt-sequential-numbers-in-xml) from just yesterday.  Although it has no actual answer, the comments on that question seem mostly to apply here, too.